# Vue, computed property to add/multiply by indexed value in data object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I'm using a computed property right now to try and total up a value in my vue object data, however, It's currently just totaling for each row entry and I want to try and group by employee. My end goal is to be able to multiply hours by scans for each employee, but right now I'm just trying to figure out how I can take what I'm already doing but index it by destinct employee so each employee only has one table row on the frontend.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php 
use Carbon\Carbon;
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$date = Carbon::now();
?>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>{{$date->format($format)}}</th>
        <th>{{$date->addDay()->format($format)}}</th>
        <th>{{$date->addDay(1)->format($format)}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows">
        <td v-html="row.employee"></td>
        <td v-html="totalRequest"></td>
        <td v-html="totalRequest"></td>
        <td v-html="totalRequest"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>


<script>

  new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [
        {  
            employee: "A123",
            hours: "15",
            date: "2021-08-31",
            scans: "4"

        },
        {  
            employee: "A123",
            hours: "25",
            date: "2021-08-31",
            scans: "4"
            
        },
        {  
            employee: "D432",
            hours: "82",
            date: "2021-09-02",
            scans: "2"
            
        },
        {  
            employee: "D432",
            hours: "40",
            date: "2021-09-01",
            scans: "5"
        }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    
  },
  computed: {
    totalRequest() {
      return this.rows.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.hours, 0);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: you want something like  
{  
            employee: "A123",
            hours: "40",
            date: "2021-08-31",
            scans: "8"

        }

Comment: @MARahman right, I'm using the date as a table header so I want to get the sum of the data for that date and put it into the right column in the table basically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method to group the employees by name then map the object values to get  the totals :

```
  methods: {
    groupByField(list, field)  {
    const result = {};
    list.forEach(item => {
      const value = item[field];
      if (value) {
        if (!result[value]) {
          result[value] = [];
        }
        result[value].push(item);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
  },
  computed: {
    compRows() {
     const  a=this.groupByField(this.rows,'employee');
    let b=Object.values(a)
    return b.map(item=>{
            return { employee:item[0].employee,hours:item.reduce((acc, _item) => (+acc) + (+_item.hours), 0), scans:item.reduce((acc, _item) => (+acc) + (+_item.scans), 0),date:item[0].date}
    })
    }
  }
```

in template

```
 <tr v-for="(row, index) in compRows">
        <td >{{row.employee}}</td>
        <td >{{row.hours}}</td>
          <td >{{row.scans}}</td>
       <td >{{row.date}}</td>
      </tr>
```

**Full example**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [{
        employee: "A123",
        hours: "15",
        date: "2021-08-31",
        scans: "4"

      },
      {
        employee: "A123",
        hours: "25",
        date: "2021-08-31",
        scans: "4"

      },
      {
        employee: "D432",
        hours: "82",
        date: "2021-09-02",
        scans: "2"

      },
      {
        employee: "D432",
        hours: "40",
        date: "2021-09-01",
        scans: "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    groupByField(list, field) {
      const result = {};
      list.forEach(item => {
        const value = item[field];
        if (value) {
          if (!result[value]) {
            result[value] = [];
          }
          result[value].push(item);
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    compRows() {
      const a = this.groupByField(this.rows, 'employee');
      let b = Object.values(a)
      return b.map(item => {
        return {
          employee: item[0].employee,
          hours: item.reduce((acc, _item) => (+acc) + (+_item.hours), 0),
          scans: item.reduce((acc, _item) => (+acc) + (+_item.scans), 0),
          date: item[0].date
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
th,td{
padding:8px
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>hours</th>
        <th>scans</th>
        <th>date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in compRows">
        <td>{{row.employee}}</td>
        <td>{{row.hours}}</td>
        <td>{{row.scans}}</td>
        <td>{{row.date}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: One quick question: This doesn't work if I have multiple dates for the employee it seems, because if I have entries for three different dates it totals them all to the actual date of the first entry row

Comment: I don't understand the issue

Comment: Sorry, so for instance: In the example above employee D432 worked on 9.1.21 and 9.2.21, and in my case I'm using dates as column headers. So I'm wondering how to get a different count for each employee on a given date so that I can use v-if to put it under the matching date column

Answer (score 0):

following is the computed method you can add to your computed object in the component

```
  groupedUser() {
      let group_users = {};
      this.rows.forEach(item => {
        const value = item['employee'];
        if (value) {
          if (!group_users[value]) {
            group_users[value] = [];
          }
          group_users[value].push(item);
        }
      });
      let group_users_array =Object.values(group_users)
      return group_users_array.map(item=>{
            return { 
              employee:item[0].employee,
              hours:item.reduce((acc, _item) => (+acc) + (+_item.hours), 0),
              scans:item.reduce((acc, _item) => (+acc) + (+_item.scans), 0),
              date:item[0].date
            }
      })
    }
```

in the HTML section you need to loop over the `groupedUser` as

```
 <tr v-for="(row, index) in groupedUser">
        <td v-html="row.employee"></td>
        <td v-html="totalRequest"></td>
        <td v-html="totalRequest"></td>
        <td v-html="totalRequest"></td>
      </tr>
```

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-pasteur-20u9i?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: Thank you for this, but the sandbox doesn't seem to load for me